# Spring Boot Actuator Not Working, health check Url is not responding

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Dependencies added in the POM file. I am using Jersey with the SpringBoot

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${springBoot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>${springBoot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>${springBoot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: need more details. What version of spring boot? Have you enabled security on management apis?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found out if I run "mvn clean package" in command line and update my eclipse with maven I can see the actuator.

try launching your application in command line.